# Let C=$\left\{(t\cos(t),t\sin(t),t^2):0\le t\le\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}$. Compute $\int_CF\cdot d\text{x}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-fields, line-integrals

$\def\hl#1#2{\bbox[#1,1px]{#2}}
\def\box#1#2#3#4#5{\color{#2}{\bbox[0px, border: 2px solid #2]{\hl{#3}{\color{white}{\color{#3}{\boxed{\underline{\large\color{#1}{\text{#4}}}\\\color{#1}{#5}\\}}}}}}}
\def\verts#1{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\def\Verts#1{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\def\pra#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$

$\box{black}{black}{}
{Question}
{(a)\text{ Let F$\pra{x,y,z}=(y+z,\alpha x+z,x+\beta y)$. For what values of $\alpha$,}\\
\text{$\beta$ is F conservative. For those cases, find $f$ s.t. F$=\nabla f$}\\
(b)\text{ Let C=$\left\{(t\cos(t),t\sin(t),t^2):0\le t\le\frac{\pi}{2}\right\}$. Compute $\int_CF\cdot d\text{x}\hspace{21.3ex}$}}\\
\box{black}{red}{}
{Theorem 1.}
{\text{Let $U$ be an open subset of $\R^n$ for $n\ge2$, and let $G:U\to\R^n$ be a continuous vector}\\
\text{field. Then the following are equivalent:}\\
\text{1. There exists a function $f:U\to\R$ of class $C^1$ such that $G=\nabla f$.}\\
\text{2. $\int_CG\cdot d\text{x}$ for any closed piecewise smooth oriented curve $C$ in $U$.}\\
\text{3. $\int_{C_1}G\cdot d\text{x}=\int_{C_2}G\cdot d\text{x}$ for any two piecewise smooth oriented curves $C_1,C_2$ in $U$ that}\\
\text{ both start at the same point $P\in U$ and end at the same point $q\in U.$}
}\\
\box{black}{green}{}
{Def.(Conservative Vector Field)}
{\text{A continuous vector field $G:U\to\R^n$ is said to be conservative if any one of these cond-}\\
\text{itions is satisfied.}}\\
\box{black}{red}{}
{Theorem 2.}
{\text{If G is a conservative vector field of class $C^1$ on an open set $U\subset\R^3$, then curl G$=0.\hspace{4ex}$}}\\
\box{black}{red}{}
{Theorem 3.}
{\text{If G$:U\to\R^3$ is a $C^1$ vector field, $U$ is a convex, and curl G$=0$, then G is conservative.$\hspace{1.3ex}$}}$

**My attempts**

$(a)$ From Theorem $2.$ and $3.$ we know that

If F has convex domain, then curl F$=0$ if and only if F is conservative

As F$:U=\R^3\to\R^3$ where $U$ is convex. and
\begin{align}
\text{curl F}=&\nabla\times F\\
=&(\beta-1,0,\alpha-1)
\end{align}
i.e. curl F$=0$ if $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=1$. Therefore F$(x,y,z)=(y+z,x+z,x+y)$ have
\begin{align}
f(x,y,z)=&\int_a^xF_1(t,b,c)dt+\int_b^yF_2(x,t,c)dt+\int_c^zF_3(x,y,t)dt\\
=&\int_a^xb+c~dt+\int_b^yx+c~dt+\int_c^zx+y~dt\\
=&~x y + x z + y z-a b - a c - b c
\end{align}
Where $(a,b,c)\in U=\R^3$, take $(a,b,c)=(0,0,0)$ then $f(x,y,z)=x y + x z + y z$ s.t. F$=\nabla f$

$(b)$ Then by Fundamental Theorem of Line Integrals
\begin{align}
\int_C \text{F}\cdot d\text{x}=&\int_C \nabla f\cdot d\text{x}\\
=&f\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}\cos\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}},\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}},\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}^2}-f(0,0,0)\\
=&\cos\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}^2+\cos\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}^3+\sin\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}^3\\
=&\pra{\frac{\pi}{2}}^3
\end{align}
Is my solution correct?

Comment: It checks out, but simplifying your trig to numbers first would've sped up the process ($2$ out of the $3$ terms were automatically zero)